# Easing overlay animation with FFMPEG

Tags: animation, ffmpeg

I have an overlay on a video, that I need to move on the y axis from point A to B.

I am using this function: `if(gte(t,0.1), if(lte(t,2.0), (H-h-20-t*25), (H-h-20-50)), NAN)` to do this.

With this function, I am able to achieve linear animation. I need the animation to ease out, i.e it slows down as it approaches it's destination, point B.

What would the mathematical equation for this would be?

The variables used in the formula are:

```
H: Height of the video
h: Height of the overlay
t: Time of the video
```